# I deleted downloads folder Windows 7. How do I restore this?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I somehow deleted the downloads folder. Now, when I create the downloads folder, it shows up, then quickly disappears and shows an empty icon without a name behind it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you look in the recycle bin to see if it is there to restore?

Comment: Yes.. and it's not there. I have Recuva, but that doesn't put it back either; I only got the files back. I mean, I can put a folder in it's place, call it Downloads and make a shortcut to the favorites, but when I go to the location in my explorer, I see a white icon, no name, and can't do anything with it. The Favorites shortcut works.. but that's about it. It's not the "Downloads" folder Windows expects...